# Add value to object in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I have json object in MongoDB. I want to add a value to this object, for example in locations -> machines -> sensors. I know the _id for the machine, for the location and for the sensor. What is the most efficient way to do this?.

```
    array(
    "_id" => '547f2e4cb54b3a96203c9869',
    "name" => Array (
        "nl" => "klant1"
    ),
    "locations" => Array (
        Array (
            "_id" => "1",
            "name" => Array (
                "nl" => "location1",
            ),
            "machines" => Array (
                Array (
                    "_id" => "1",
                    "name" => Array (
                        "nl" => "boot1"
                    ),
                    "sensors" => Array (
                        Array (
                            "_id" => "1",
                            "log" => Array (
                            )
                        ),
                        Array (
                            "_id" => "2",
                            "log" => Array (
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
                Array (
                    "_id" => "2",
                    "name" => Array (
                        "nl" => "boot2"
                    ),
                    "sensors" => Array (
                        Array (
                            "_id" => "1",
                            "log" => Array (
                            )
                        ),
                        Array (
                            "_id" => "2",
                            "log" => Array (
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ), 
                Array (
                    "_id" => "3",
                    "name" => Array (
                        "nl" => "boot3"
                    ),
                    "sensors" => Array (
                        Array (
                            "_id" => "1",
                            "log" => Array (
                            )
                        ),
                        Array (
                            "_id" => "2",
                            "log" => Array (
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: Can you please post your schema, for better readability.

Comment: You should use MySQL for this. ;)

Comment: To match into arrays nested 2 deep with an `_id` for each level would require [SERVER-831](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/server-831). Generally, the way around this (and a way that often produces better results in the end), is to redesign the schema so there are no nested arrays. It's hard to say how best to do that without knowing a lot more about your use case, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super easy. You can either do a [findAndModify](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.findandmodify.php) call. Or if you want to do it a little more manually, you can do:

```
$collection = $mongo->your_collection;
$obj = $collection->findOne($query);
$obj = $obj['locations']['machines']['sensors'][] = $new_sensor;
$collection->save($obj);
```

Mongo is smart enough to identify the object using `_id` key which causes it to treat these saves as updates to existing objects. Without it you'd be creating new objects with this.